# Difference between char (*fptr)() and char (*fptr())()?

Tags: c

I understand that `char (*fptr)()` is a function(void) pointer that returns a char.
But what is `char (*fptr())()`?
When would be appropriate to use this?

Comment: [https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*fptr%28%29%29%28%29](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*fptr%28%29%29%28%29)

Comment: Why I got -1 for asking a question?  This would help me to write a better question.

Comment: @Ryan - I got this from the link:declare` fptr as function returning pointer to function returning char`.  I know this.  But can you provide an example?  Thanks

Comment: An example of what? A function that returns a pointer to a function?

Comment: @Ryan - Yes.  I was able to figure out `char (*(*fptr1)(char))();`. But not `char (*fptr())()`.[ideon link](http://ideone.com/kFXlot)